# Wordpress "get_the_excerpt($product_id);" return html?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

As mentioned in the title, I've got a problem with the function : get_the_excerpt($product_id); which I would like to return html but instead it put me some quotes ("") around as you can see there: https://eshoes.com.au/product/carton-multi-test/

Please click to the first radio button to see the result I would like to arrive (the table in html and not a

tags..)

I'm trying to hook a part of code from the plugin [Composite Products](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/composite-products/) to have the product_description already displayed under my radio button without clicking on it.

Made a bit of research and apparently it's a recurrent problem with "the_excerpt" which convert the text with

around but impossible to figure out a way to discard that.

My code:

```
`$product_description = get_the_excerpt($product_id);
`<?php echo '<span class="radio_button_price price">' . $product_description . '</span>'; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using a function already builtin the *composite product plugin*.

Inside the following file: woocommerce-composite-products\templates\single-product\ **component-option-radio-button.php** you can replace/add (line 42) beside echo $product_price_html; this line:

```
            *echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_composited_product_excerpt', wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $product_description ) ) ), $product_id, $component_id, $composite );*
```

That's doing the job straight away and interpreting it in HTML taking care  of the "tags" <>

Hope it helps :)